# Bootstrap Tooltip shows up under the element

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, z-index

The tooltip is showing under the element when I hover over it. The z-index of the element is 2, while the tooltip has 1030. I'm not sure what's going on. It's only for some elements too, even though they have the same markup.

Here's the page that it's happening on http://darebounty.com/streams/11

It's the shapes on a page at the bottom (red, blue, yellow, etc) #rune_page_view

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help to mention **which** elements this is happening with

Comment: look at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376309/z-index-not-overlaying-over-divs-further-down-in-the-dom/3376907)

Comment: A higher z-index on an element does not necessarily guarantee it will be displayed above other elements with a lower z-index. See [this explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context) of the stacking context.

Comment: I've added which elements it's doing it to in the OP, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue and was messing around with z-indexing in order to solve it, but it ended up being futile. I then checked out [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tooltip.asp).

I found the "data-container='body'" attribute very useful. It was able to make my tooltips show up over everything (so that the user could actually read them), which is what I imagine most people would want.

Hope that helps anyone coming upon this in the future. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue.

In my case the reason was that the enclosing `DIV` element had `overflow: hidden` set.

I changed it to `overflow: visible` and it worked.

Maybe this will help :).